# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null ///// from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: javascript

I have an XML document with a list of senators. Each senator has a party and a name. Looks like:

```
<senators>
  <senator>
    <name>Chuck Schumer</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
  </senator>
  <senator>
    <name>Dick Durbin</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
  </senator>
```

etc

The document is called partyList.xml.

When I try to load it into a JSON object, I get two errors just trying to simply display it to see if it loaded correctly:

```
partyWise.js:23 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/Shiny/partyList.xml' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

and

```
partyWise.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

I have no idea why. Interestingly if I take out my very last error handling bit, the TypeError goes away, but I still don't get a display of the file as a string. I get  [][].

```
window.onload = init;
var senatorList;  
function init() {
     // initialize the JSON array
    senatorList = new Array();

    // load the partylist xml file
    makeRequest("partyList.xml");
}

var xhr;

function makeRequest(url) { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = loadXMLSenators;
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send(null);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 
            "Sorry, couldn't create an XMLHttpRequest";
    }
}

// callback function when data is loaded
function loadXMLSenators() {

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            // get all the senator elements
            var allSenators = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("senator");
            for (var i = 0; i < allSenators.length; i++) {
                var name = 
                    allSenators[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent;
                var party = 
                    allSenators[i].getElementsByTagName("party")[0].textContent;

                // create a new JSON object for each senator
                var newSenator = {
                    "name" : name,
                    "party" : party
                };
                // add the object to the array
                senatorList.push(newSenator);
            }

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 
                    "Loaded " + senatorList.length + " senators. (I AM THE SENATE)";

        } else {
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 
                    "There was a problem w-- I AM THE SENATE" + xhr.status;
        }
    }
   var x = JSON.stringify(senatorList);
document.write(x);
}
```

Comment: use a http server if you want to do AJAX - everything is cross origin when serving using `file:///`

Comment: Ok, running it in MAMP fixes the first error, but I stil get  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: do you have an element with `id="status"` - not `"Status"` or `"STATUS"` but `"status"`

Comment: oh, wait `document.write(x);` ... don't do that

Comment: I added the element. One problem solved.
As far as the document write, I have a long ways to go on the functionality of this program. I just wanted to test to see if the xml document parsed at all. how would you?

Comment: debugging using `document.write` will cause more problems than it solves ... use `console.log` (or console.info, console.error etc) and learn to use the browser developer tools console

Comment: the console isn't that complicated. I just suck at coding overall. Thanks for the help guys.